# motoman_driver compatibility (only Kinetic)?

Tags: ros, motoman-driver, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

motoman_driver can only work with kinetic version of Moveit!; ROS right?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316704/motoman_driver-compatibility-(only-kinetic)?/) by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2019-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaik (and afaict) the `motoman_driver` package can both be built and used under Melodic.

I've just compile-tested that in a Melodic docker container.

> with kinetic version of Moveit!;

I'm not sure how MoveIt factors into this, but seeing as none of the action interfaces have changed, I would say it should work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on 2019-02-26**:
thanks @gvdhoorn, there is no official release that´s why i thought.